# Methods stubbed out in uiautomator.jar in android

Tags: java, android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator, uidevice

I am using [uiautomator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html) APIs in my project. I found that `uiautomator.jar` has stubbed APIs while their implementation is present in `sources` under sdk folder.

```
public static UiDevice getInstance()
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Why do you care if `getInstance()` is stubbed or not?

Comment: I want to invoke UiDevice method dumpWindowHierarchy(String fileName). Since, UiDevice is a singleton class, I need to call getInstance().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since, UiDevice is a singleton class, I need to call getInstance()

Call `getUiDevice()` on [your `UiAutomatorTestCase`](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiAutomatorTestCase.html) to get your `UiDevice` instance.

Comment: Just checked: UiAutomatorTestCase method getUiDevice() is also stubbed out.

Comment: @Aashish: Not on the device.  All the `uiautomator.jar` is for is to satisfy the compiler, just as does the `android.jar` file for building your APKs.

Comment: my requirement is to implement code in app which will dump the view heirarchy of the app. Am I doing right? What do you suggest?

Comment: @Aashish: You are welcome to dump the view hierarchy of your own activity by going to the root view and recursing through the tree of children. This does not require anything from the `uiautomator` framework.

Comment: I used "uiautomator dump" through adb. It dumps a lot of information in the file, which I cannot get through traversing the view tree. What if the view group of activity is populated in the native side? I will appreciate if I could use dumpViewHeirarchy in my code. Is there a way?

Comment: @Aashish: "It dumps a lot of information in the file, which I cannot get through traversing the view tree" -- such as? "What if the view group of activity is populated in the native side?" -- NDK apps do not have access to the view hierarchy.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52328/discussion-between-aashish-and-commonsware)

Comment: Like bounds of view, package name,
Ok. Tell me one thing. If I still wish to go it with my way, will I be able to do this?
Won't it be better to use the existing API instead of writing ours?

Comment: "Like bounds of view, package name" -- those are available from the Android SDK, via methods on `View` and `Activity`. "will I be able to do this?" -- no. "Won't it be better to use the existing API instead of writing ours?" -- it is not an existing API for an Android app. It is an existing API for a test suite. It is specifically designed to allow testing across multiple applications, for integration testing, and therefore can only be used from a test suite, for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It really helped a lot. And these test suites will only run through `adb` from command line? And there is no alternative other than recursively traversing the view tree of activity?

Comment: @Aashish: "And these test suites will only run through adb from command line?" -- correct. "And there is no alternative other than recursively traversing the view tree of activity?" -- not that I am aware of. The recursion itself shouldn't be more than 10 lines of code. From there, it is merely a matter of gathering whatever specific information you need about your UI.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense. Does it mean that the monitor.bat and uiautomatorviewer use same set of APIs as `adb shell uiautomator dump` does? I mean we cannot tweak monitor.bat/uiautomatorviewer to get view heirarchy when device is not connected? Sigh! There is only one way, use the view tree.

Comment: @Aashish: "Does it mean that the monitor.bat and uiautomatorviewer use same set of APIs as adb shell uiautomator dump does?" -- I presume so, though I have not looked.

Comment: Thanks for all the info :)